# React still having to click twice for updating a state although useEffect with dependency

Tags: reactjs

Here is a summary of my sign-up modal component below:

```
  const auth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);
  const authError = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.error);

  const { isLoading, isAuthenticated, user, error, isSuccessful } = auth;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  console.log("useForm err", errors);
  const { addToast } = useToasts();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(removeError()); // cleaning previous authError message when modal opens
  }, [isSuccessful]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const { email, username, password } = data;
    
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_USER_REQUEST,
      data: { email, username, password },
    });

    if (isSuccessful) {
      addToast(`Thank you for signing up! Now you can log in`, {
        appearance: "success",
        autoDismiss: true,
      });
      onClose();
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };
```

auth reducer below:

```
const initialState: AuthState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isSuccessful: false,
  user: null,
  error: null,
};


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  return produce(state, (draft) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case REGISTER_USER_REQUEST: {
        draft.isLoading = true;
        draft.isSuccessful = false;
        draft.error = null;
        break;
      }
      case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS: {
        draft.isLoading = false;
        draft.isSuccessful = true;
        draft.error = null;
        break;
      }
      case REGISTER_USER_FAILURE: {
        draft.isLoading = false;
        draft.isSuccessful = false;
        draft.error = action.error;
        break;
      }
```

I noticed that once sign-up form filled and click the submit button *(expecting **isSuccessful** changes into *true*)* but **isSuccessful** state is still *false* and then I have to click the submit button once more then it changes into *true* as the state works asynchronously in React so I put it into the dependency of useEffect but no luck, still does not work.
Anything I have missed?

Comment: can you show the reducer, like how it is changing the value of isSuccessful in state.auth?

Comment: @HaiderAliAnjum
I've added reducer code

Comment: is the dispatch(removeError()) call hitting the action 'REGISTER_USER_FAILURE'?

Comment: No, there's error reducer 'ADD_ERROR' which takes errors from try/catch block of REGISTER_USER api and 'REMOVE_ERROR' return {error: null}

Comment: Can you see redux dev tools in your browser, to see the list of redux actions called on the first time your click the button as you say it keeps on returning false. My assumption right now is that you are removing error on each change in the key `isSuccessful` this leads to call removeError on every REQUEST_USER_... action.
so somehow, you REGISTER_USER_FAILURE is also getting invoked to set it false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move this block into your effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (isSuccessful) {
   addToast(`Thank you for signing up! Now you can log in`, {
     appearance: "success",
     autoDismiss: true,
   });
   onClose();
 }
}, [isSuccessful])
```

You check the value of `isSuccessful` right after dispatching the action that will change the state at some point, that's too soon.